# Java's BigInteger C# in Base 32

Tags: java, c#, random, biginteger, base32

How would one convert the following line of Java to C#. It generates a random BigInteger of 130 bits in size, converts it to a string in base 32 (i.e. *not decimal*) and then manipulates the string:

```
new BigInteger(130, new SecureRandom()).toString(32).replace("/", "w").toUpperCase(Locale.US);
```

How can I achieve that in C#?

- Generate a random 130 bit BigInteger
- convert it to a string in base 32

As far as the random BigInteger I have this function:

```
static BigInteger RandomInteger(int bits)
{
            RNGCryptoServiceProvider secureRandom = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider();
            // make sure there is extra room for a 0-byte so our number isn't negative
            // in the case that the msb is set
            var bytes = new byte[bits / 8 + 1];
            secureRandom.GetBytes(bytes);
            // mask off excess bits
            bytes[bytes.Length - 1] &= (byte)((1 << (bits % 8)) - 1);
            return new BigInteger(bytes);
}
```

taken from this question which does not address the base 32 conversion: [Equivalent of Java's BigInteger in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002856/equivalent-of-javas-biginteger-in-c-sharp)

However I'm not sure if that function is correct as well.

The C# code I have so far, RandomInteger being the function described above:

```
RandomInteger(130).ToString().Replace("/","w").ToUpper(CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo("en-US"));
```

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking. Instead of providing an incomplete Java example for someone else to translate for you, provide a good [mcve] that shows the **C#** code you have so far, explain what that code does and what you want it to do instead. Explain also why http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21002856/equivalent-of-javas-biginteger-in-c-sharp doesn't fully address your concern.

Comment: @PeterDuniho, I added why it doesn't fully address my concern and my C# code.

Comment: It is pretty clear: How can I generate a 130 bit random BigInteger converted to base 32 in C#?

Comment: FWIW, @hl3mukkel 's implemenation is indeed better. C#'s BigInteger expects the byte array to be two's complement, and if the top bit of the most significant byte is set, it is interpreted as negative, which is not good for a random number. So he adds at least one zero byte at the top. His calculation of the arrays size is better too.

Answer (score 1):

The above code has quite a few bugs, if bits are whole the last number gets masked out entirely and there's a chance that the number gets positive because the new BigInteger(byte[]) overload expects a little endian signed number, so you have to prepend it with a 0 byte

```
    static BigInteger RandomInteger(int bits)
    {
        var bytes = new byte[(bits + 7) / 8 + 1];

        using (var rng = new RNGCryptoServiceProvider())
            rng.GetBytes(bytes, 0, bytes.Length - 1);

        var remainingBits = bits % 8;

        if (remainingBits > 0)
            bytes[bytes.Length - 2] &= (byte)((1 << remainingBits) - 1);

        return new BigInteger(bytes);
    }
```

This would work I suppose

Comment: What you described here is not an answer, and does not cover base 32 conversion. this should be a comment

Comment: The fact that it is little-endian is no problem, but the fact that BigInteger expects a two's-complement byte array. That is why you prepend a 0 as most significant byte, I guess, so it is always interpreted as positive? Your version is indeed better. I think it is a (partial) answer.

Answer (score 1):

#### Base 32 string

This is how I would convert to base 32. Note that I can not test this here and that my C# is a little rusty, but I think the following should be good enough to get you going (if someone sees a syntax error, please edit it out):

```
static string BigIntegerToString32(BigInteger bi)
{
    // Obvious shortcut -- avoids problems later on.
    if (bi == BigInteger.Zero)
        return("0");

    readonly char[] digits = new char[] { 
        '0', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7',
        '8', '9', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F',
        'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N',
        'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V'
    };

    // Only work with positive BigInteger.
    BigInteger value = BigInteger.Abs(bi);

    // Collects one digit on each iteration.
    StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();

    // This value is needed more often -- only converted once.
    BigInteger thirtyOne = 0x1F;

    while (value > BigInteger.Zero)
    {   
        // get next digit: value % 32  
        result.Insert(0, digits[(int)(value & thirtyOne)]);

        // shift out last digit: value = value / 32
        value >>= 5;
    }

    // prepend '-' if negative
    if (bi < BigInteger.Zero)
        result.Insert(0, '-');

    return result.ToString();
}
```

Note that for huge `BigIntegers`, it might make sense to use a faster, but more complicated algorithm (as I do in my Delphi `BigInteger` implementation), although this here is probably more or less how C#'s `BigInteger` (which does not use more sophisticated routines for large BigIntegers, AFAIK, unlike Java) does this too, for base 10.

#### Random 130 bit BigInteger

The answer by @hl3mukkel does a much better job of generating an `n` bit random `BigInteger` than the code you found and posted, so use his code to generate such a `BigInteger`.